# createuser: could not connect to database postgres:

Tags: macos, postgresql

I am trying to create a user in PostgreSQL in Mac with the following command 
        `createuser -P project_user`
It then prompts
        `Enter password for new role:`
        `Enter it again:`
        `Password:`

I enter thrice the new password for project_user but authentication fails with the below error.
    `createuser: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user <my_mac_user_name>.`

I was able to enter psql terminal with following command and password as 'postgres'
        `sudo -u postgres psql`
        `\du` displays the user project_user.
But same error appears when trying to create database with below command
        `createdb -O project_user DB_NAME`

Comment: Without any additional options `createuser` (and `createdb`) try to authenticate against the database with the username of the local user, i.e. `my_mac_user_name`. Either use `-U postgres` or create`my_mac_user_name` as a database user with the required privileges.